# Layout issues when using `subcaption` together with `sidecap`

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption, sidecap

I am using the `sidecap` package for side captions. I also want to have subfigures (for example, three or four subfigures labeled with a), b), c) and d), respectively).

When *not* using the `SCfigure` environment, this is what I get (the figures are aligned correctly, but the caption is obviously not at the side):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{scrbook}         
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage[wide]{sidecap}                                                      % custom captions on the side
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}                                                     % captions should be on top
\sidecaptionvpos{table}{t}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
    format=plain,
    labelfont={bf,sf},
    nooneline,
    textfont={it}]{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[twoside]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
                    left=24.8mm,
                    top=27.4mm,
                    %headheight=\baselineskip,
                    %headsep=2\baselineskip,
                    textwidth=135mm,
                    marginparsep=8.2mm,
                    marginparwidth=28mm
                    }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054a}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a}}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054b}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b}}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054c}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{c}}
\caption{A test figure}\label{fig:01:054}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image: using <code>figure</code>]

When using `SCfigure` but with only two subfigures, the result is satisfying, correctly displaying the side caption:

```
\begin{SCfigure}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054a}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a}}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054b}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b}}
%  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054c}}
%          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{c}}
\caption{A test figure}\label{fig:01:054}
\end{SCfigure}
```

[image: using <code>SCfigure</code> with two subfigures]

When I uncomment the last `\subcaptionbox`, this is what I get:

[image: Using <code>SCfigure</code> with three subfigures]

What do I have to do in order to display three or more figures of `width=0.5\textwidth` correctly like in the `figure` environment? Can't be that I'm the only one who's using side captions in conjunction with subfigures....

**Edit:** In [this German forum thread](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=72437), the author of the `subcaption` package claims that it is compatible with `sidecap`.

Comment: Although I don't think an MWE will change anything here because the package maintainer or another person is likely to know the answer without needing an MWE, I added one...

Comment: @wnstnsmth Re: _another person is likely to know the answer without needing an MWE_ - Quite the opposite is often true. Also some people decide not to help simply because an MWE is missing. So: thanks for posting one!

Comment: Alright.. I hope it works with the information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you the more powerful and flexible [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package (in fact, the author of caption also suggest this package as an alternative to `sidecap`).

I commented out a spurious blank space after the first `\subcaptionbox` and added a line changing command `\\` after the second one; I also added a "fake" four image (a rule of zero height and `0.5\textwidth` width) to have the third image flushed left instead of centered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{scrbook}         
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
    format=plain,
    labelfont={bf,sf},
    nooneline,
    textfont={it}]{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[twoside]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
                    left=24.8mm,
                    top=27.4mm,
                    %headheight=\baselineskip,
                    %headsep=2\baselineskip,
                    textwidth=135mm,
                    marginparsep=8.2mm,
                    marginparwidth=28mm
                    }

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{margins=hangright,capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={top,right},floatwidth=\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054a}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054b}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:01:054c}}
          {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\rule{.5\textwidth}{0pt}
\caption{A test figure}\label{fig:01:054}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't really work here. All images get displayed underneath each other (not only where I inserted a "\\"), and because of that, the whole figure gets pushed to a new **left** page where the side caption actually should be left, not right (thus I should adjust `\thisfloatsetup`, I guess, but this doesn't change the stacking of the images). http://imgur.com/ENzOW4Z     Also, the obvious disadvantage with this approach is that I always need to adjust these `\thisfloatsetup` parameters depending on whether the figure is displayed on a left or right page. Mhhh...

Comment: I found out that when not using `\thisfloatsetup` (i.e. commenting it out), the images are still stacked on top of each other (also when only using two images). Only when I don't load the `floatrow` package do I get two images on one line. So weird.

Comment: @wnstnsmth For the first problem: please notice the `%` character suppressing the spurious blank space at the end of the first `\subcaptionbox` in my code. You are not using this and that will cause the undesired effect mentioned.

Comment: @wnstnsmth For the other remark, please read the package documentation; `floatrow` is really powerful. You can specify `capbesideposition=inside`, or `capbesideposition=outside` for example, to avoid manual specifications for each float.

Comment: Regarding the first problem, now I know what `%` does, thanks. It works now. Regarding the second problem, `margins=hangoutside` and `capbesideposition={top,inside}` did the trick. Now I have only one concern left. When using the `SCfigure` environment, labels are like so: "Figure 1.2: Lorem ipsum", but when using `figure`, the numbering contains a final point, like so: "Figure 1.2.: Lorem ipsum". I want the latter to be the same as the first (because I will be using `figure` only for multi-figure panels). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer in the `caption` manual.